# AzureAD multiteenant app - "Authorization_RequestDenied": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am referring to [Multitenant-saas-app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect) sample. I am trying to get an access token to access Graph API and then get access token silently and access the graph api again.

Get Authorisation Code with /common endpoint for the multi-tenant-app,

```
private string resourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";

 string authorizationRequest = String.Format(
                "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&state={3}",
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"]),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.windows.net"),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(this.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString() + "/Onboarding/ProcessCode"),
                 Uri.EscapeDataString(stateMarker)
                 );
return new RedirectResult(authorizationRequest);
```

Redirected with authorisation code, (/Onboarding/ProcessCode)

```
  ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"],
                                                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Password"]);
                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/");

                //Get token to access grapgh API
                AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                   code, new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, resourceID);

                AuthenticationHelper.token = result.AccessToken;
```

This works fine and I get the access token where I can access the AzureAD resources for the tenant.

```
 ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
                IPagedCollection<IUser> pagedCollection = await client.Users.ExecuteAsync();
```

Now I try to get get the token for offline access from the token cache. This time I create AuthenticationContext for the tenant. (I tried /common as well)
This gets me a new accesstoken silently.

```
 string resourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";
            //Test
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"],
                                                                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Password"]);

            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.net");

            var auth = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceID, credential);

            var newToken = auth.AccessToken;
            //Set the token for this session
            AuthenticationHelper.token = auth.AccessToken;
```

Then I try to access the API as previous,

```
ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
                IPagedCollection<IUser> pagedCollection = await client.Users.ExecuteAsync();
```

and I get the following exception,

> Error = "Authorization_RequestDenied": "Insufficient privileges to
>   complete the operation."

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Here is my app permissions,

[image]

Comment: A tenant admin needs to grant access to the application when you are using multi-tenant apps. Perhaps that is the problem? Are there any further error message details?

Answer (score 0):

To list the users using the Azure AD graph REST, we require the **Read all users' basic profile** or **Read all users' full profiles** if you were not a global admin in the tenant.

And if you were the **Global Admin** in the tenant, the **Access the directory as the sign-in user** should also work to list users rest API.

And more detail about the scopes about Azure AD graph, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes).

And for the cache issue, since you didn't provide custom cache, it would use the default cache based on the platform. For example, if you were developing an .Net application, the cache is using the memory to store the object. So it only works before you restart the application.